# Sequence contains more than one element when using Contains in LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first, asp.net-core

The following code is throwing an InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element. The errors occurs whether I have the Include statement or not.

```
long[] customerIDs; //Method parameter. Has valid values


var results = from x in DB.CycleCounts
              //.Include(y => y.CustomerInventoryItem)
              select x;

if (customerIDs != null && customerIDs.Length > 0)
{
    results = from x in results
              where customerIDs.Contains(x.CustomerInventoryItem.CustomerID)
              select x;

}

var cycleCounts = await results.ToListAsync(); //throws InvalidOperationException
```

I am using ASP5 RC1 (Core), and Entity Framework 7

Comment: I guess you are trying to store multiple lists in `cycleCounts` where `cycleCounts` is single-dimensional. Isnt it possible to debug this single line and checking for correct output?

Comment: Is the code example correct? You access cycleCounts in the if-block, but declare it afterwards. Do you mean "results = from x in results..."?

Comment: Sorry about that, I renamed a few things after pasting my code. I fixed it now, thanks for catching it.

Comment: Are you trying to return results for any `customerId` in `customerIDs[]` ?

Comment: Yes, customerIDs[] is a filter. If customerIDs has a value, I only want cycle counts who's customer ID is in the array. I tried using Any() instead of Contains() but it throws the same Exception.

Comment: I would suggest you do it in 1 statement, then, using the join syntax - i.e.  `from cc in DB.CycleCounts join cust in customerIDs on .... select cc` http://www.dotnetperls.com/join

Comment: the reason for the error is that you re-referencing `x` in the `contains`.  `x` is in results already, what you needed was a member of `customerIDs`

Comment: @HughJones I thought so too at first, so I changed the name of the variable in the second query, and the error still remains.

`results = from y in results...`

I feel like this is something that worked in EF6

Comment: Is the missing "s" in `customerID.Contains(...)` a typo? Or did you define an array with a similar name elsewhere?

Comment: @StephenReindl it was another type. Whoops.

Comment: ok then ... narrow it down... Any differrence if you run the second query on an in memory representation (i.e. pass a .ToList() to the first query?)

Comment: The problem appears to be caused by the nested properties being passed to the Contains method.

If the code could be written as `where customerIDs.Contains(x.CustomerID)` it would work, but EF can't seem to figure out how to convert to SQL when there is an extra level of nesting. `where customerIDs.Contains(x.CustomerInventoryItem.CustomerID)`

I created a quick sample project that reproduces the error https://github.com/MaxxDelusional/EntityFrameworkContainsExample

Answer (score 0):

I not sure how look your models, but I think that they looks like something below (relationship between CycleCounts and CustomerInventoryItems as many-to-one as I expect):

**Models:**

```
[Table("CustomerInventorys")]
public class CustomerInventory
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CustomerID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CycleCount> CycleCounts { get; set; }
}

[Table("CycleCounts")]
public class CycleCount
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long CustomerInventoryItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerInventory CustomerInventoryItem  { get; set; }
}
```

So if my suggestions are correct I recommend you to rewrite you code like this:

```
    IQueryable<CycleCount> results = null;

    if (customerIDs != null && customerIDs.Length > 0)
    {
        results = from invent in DB.CustomerInventorys
                  where customerIDs.Contains(invent.CustomerID)
                  join cycle in DB.CycleCounts on invent.ID equals cycle.CustomerInventoryItemID                          
                  select cycle;    
    }
    else
        results = DB.CycleCounts;

    var cycleCounts = await results.ToListAsync();
```